# Error in capturing "MMM" DateTime format with libpcap

Tags: c#, linux, date-format, libpcap, packet-capture

I have programmed a packet simulator in C# that produces some UDP packets and sends them to a given IP address. The simulator produces and sends packets successfully to my UBUNTU virtual machine but there is a problem in destination. In C# program, data format defined as :

```
namespace PacketSimulator
{
    static class Program
    {
        public static string DateFormat = "MMM dd HH:mm:ss";
        .
        .
    }
}
```

and packets Are sent by :

```
namespace PacketSimulator
{
    class ConnectionInfo
    {
        public DateTime DATE_TIME;
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return DATE_TIME.ToString(Program.DateFormat) + " " + "10.0.72.45 " + ....

        }
     }
}
```

But at Linux side, what i can capture is a bit different with what i have sent:

```
???? 26 18:17:10 10.0.72.45
```

The Month format defined as "MMM" (three letters month name)in C#  program but what Lipcap captures is a four letters text as ????

What i need is to receive packets in defined format not with four ? sign.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: 1. How are you encoding the text when you send the packet? Does this match the receiving end? 2. Have you looked at what is on the wire (eg. WireShark)? 3. Generally for IPC the best format for dates and times is ISO-8601: `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss` which avoids all the ambiguities and localisation issues of other formats.

Comment: @Richard 1- no encoding is used. 2- i use libpcap library as mention in question body 3- Thanks

Comment: Of course an encoding is used (it may be implicit, but it is there): a UDP packet's content is an array of octets, but strings in .NET are not an array of bytes, so conversion – encoding – must happen. You need to control this.

Comment: @Richard there are some texts (e.g 10.0.72.45) which is received without any change. Only Month name changes to ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDN :

> The "MMM" custom format specifier represents the abbreviated name of
>   the month. The localized abbreviated name of the month is retrieved
>   from the DateTimeFormatInfo.AbbreviatedMonthNames property of the
>   current or specified culture.

Try passing in `CultureInfo`

```
return DATE_TIME.ToString(Program.DateFormat,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " " + "10.0.72.45 " + ....
```

If that fails, then it must be that libpcap can not access DateTimeFormatInfo.AbbreviatedMonthNames for some reason.